# “S'est fait renvoyer” or “s'est faite renvoyer” ?

Tags: verbes, accord, participe-passé, pronoms-réfléchis

How does it work here, do we say

> Elle s’est fait renvoyer de l’appartement.

or

> Elle s’est faite renvoyer de l’appartement.

?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is :

> Elle s'est fait renvoyer de l'appartement

The rule is the following :

> When immediately followed by an infinitive, the past participle
>   (participe passé) of the verb "faire" is invariant.

Answer (score 1):

> Elle s'est fait renvoyer de l'appartement.

"Fait" is followed by an infinitive and is invariable, so.
[Rules](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/%C2%AB-elle-s%E2%80%99est-faite-faire-%C2%BB-ou-%C2%AB-elle-s%E2%80%99est-fait-faire-%C2%BB)